# Rails: Validate dates in model before type_cast

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date

When an ill-formatted or invalid date (e.g. February 29th on non-leap years) is input in a form, any validation appears to access a nil value. The reason for this is that validation in Rails occurs AFTER type casting the original string to a date variable: If this fails (for above reasons), the type casting returns a nil value which is stored in the attribute of the model.

I found out that I can access the original date string via the `attribute_before_type_cast` functions and was thus able to write the following custom validator:

```
class DateFieldValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each( record, attribute, value )

    # this may be interesting only if value could not be read

    return unless value.nil?

    # but not if original value was blank

    original_value = record.read_attribute_before_type_cast( attribute )
        return if original_value.blank?

    # ignore any other value but String

    return unless original_value.is_a? String

    # _parse must return some useful values

    parsed_value = Date._parse( original_value )
    unless [ :year, :mon, :mday ].all? { |key| parsed_value.has_key?( key ) }
      record.errors.add( attribute, ( options[ :message ] || I18n.t( 'validators.date_field.bad_syntax' )))
      return
    end

    # valid_date? must return true

    unless Date.valid_date?( parsed_value[ :year ], parsed_value[ :mon ], parsed_value[ :mday ])
      record.errors.add( attribute, ( options[ :message ] || I18n.t( 'validators.date_field.bad_date' )))
      return
    end

  # date is OK

  end
end
```

This works fine but if the date is required (validate is with presence: true) I get two validation errors, one from my validator, the other from Rails, telling the user that the required attribute is missing.

This could be irritating to the user especially as the original bad value is (currently) not shown on the form. Should I display the original value in the form and remove the error message generated by Rails?

P.S. A date picker as helper to insert only valid dates is not an option as I have to consider dates far into the future which would require lots of clicking around in the date picker.

Comment: So don't use the rails validation, just yours on that attribute.

Comment: @japed: That would be the next question: Is there a way to DRY up the code such that I could use the same validator for required and optional dates...

Comment: For the records: I just found a solution to my question above! The options hash can be filled with my own parameters (and values), e.g. 'presence: true'. Expanding my solution above with "if options[ :presence ] && value.blank? record.errors.add( attribute, :blank )" allows me to use validates :attribute, date_field: {presence: true/false}.